# How to create view with the name which can be pass through function as a parameter in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a view in postgreSQL using function. I want a view name in such a way that, which should be pass by the function as a parameter. For example..

--Table

```
create table test
( rollno int,
  name text);
```

--Function to create a view

```
create or replace function fun_view(roll int)
returns void as
$Body$
declare
       rec record;
begin
       for rec in select * from test where rollno=roll loop
           create or replace view "---Name of view should be roll---" as 
           select rollno from test;
       end loop;
$Body$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need PL/PgSQL's dynamic SQL `EXECUTE` command:

```
EXECUTE format('create or replace view %I as ...', roll::text);
```

See: [dynamic SQL in PL/PgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Craig Ringer. It really works fine.